# D3: Format date type

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js, formatting

I want to format a date in D3. Here is my code:

```
var format = d3.time.format("%Y/%m");

var dates = data.map(function(d){ return new Date("2016/01/03"); });
 var formDate = format.parse(dates);
  console.log(formDate);
```

My formDate seems to be null, don't know why.

In my chart the values are not displayed at all. How should I format it to get something like `"2016/01"` ?

Comment: I'm not sure any of this code is doing what you think it is doing. What are you actually attempting to achieve?

Comment: I want to construct a bar chart in D3 and I want to format the values on my x axis which are of type date.

Comment: The sample code you posted doesn't really convey this. Are your values string representations of a date, or an actual javascript Date object?

Comment: javascript Date object

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you need to use `format` as a function itself.

`format.parse()` is for parsing string representations of a date into a javascript Date (the opposite operation from what you are looking for).

For instance, given a date, 'd', you would use the following code to get what you would like:

```
var format = d3.time.format("%Y/%m");
var formattedDate = format(d);
```

Further adding to the confusion, it looks like you attempted to use `parse()` on a collection of dates. both `parse()` and `format()` only support individual strings/Dates respectively, so keep that in mind.

You haven't given enough information to suggest what structure your data is in, but the above should be enough to help you formulate a transform function for your x axis labels.